# How to properly use assertRaises() with str type objects

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-models

I'm trying to write a simple unittest that tests if my `fake_user's` (created via FactoryBoy) `username` already exists.  (i.e someone has already created a user w/ the same username).

A simple version of the test would be as follows:

```
# factories.py
import factory


class BaseUserFactory(factory.DjangoModelFactory):
    """A factory for creating User objects."""

    username = factory.Faker('word')
    email = factory.lazy_attribute(lambda x: '%s@email.com' % (x.username))

    class Meta:
        """User factory Meta attributes."""

        model = models.User
        django_get_or_create = ('username', 'email')
```

a simple test:

```
#test_user.py
from django.test import TestCase
from django.apps import apps

from . import factories


class TestAccountModels(TestCase):
    """Testing the User models."""

    users = [user.username for user in models.User.objects.all()]
    fake_user = factories.BaseUserFactory.create()

    def test_username_available(self):
        self.assertIn(self.fake_user.username, self.users)
```

now for context, say my (already existing) `username`(s) are 'Brody' and 'Sam'.  When `test_username_available` runs I get back:

```
self.assertIn(self.fake_user.username, self.users)
AssertionError: 'suscipit' not found in ['Sam', 'Brody']
```

My questions is this:

I want to write a test to test for this specific error.  I tried something like this:

```
    def test_clean_username(self):
    self.assertRaises(
        AssertionError, '"{0}" unexpectedly found in "{1}"'.format(
            self.proposed_username,
            self.taken_usernames,
            )
        )
```

but keep getting `str object is not callable` (on `taken_usernames`); and I get that, but just cant seem to find a workaround

where:

```
proposed_username = self.fake_user.username
self.taken_usernames = [self.user.username for self.user in self.user]
```

I've tried re-working this different ways but it seems the problem is linked to this (from another answer, i had this jotted down somewhere so no link unfortunately):

```
You are using self.assertRaises() incorrectly. 
It has to call the test function for you, in order to catch the exception
self.assertRaises(mouse16.BadInternalCallException,
stack.insertn, [8, 4, 12], 16)

You were passing in the result of the stack.insertn() call (which didn't raise an exception, but returned either None or an integer instead), and that return value is not callable.
An older version of the method accepted None for that argument as well, which is no longer supported, hence the deprecation warning when None is passed in versus an integer.
The better way is to use self.assertRaises() as a context manager:
with self.assertRaises(mouse16.BadInternalCallException):
stack.insertn([8, 4, 12], 16
```

Do i need to use the context manager? I feel like this should be easier and i'm making it harder than it has to be.  Originally I was trying to pull the attributes out of model.**dict** but ended up taking someone elses advice and used some list comprehension.

This works outside of of a TestCase method/class.  I feel there should be a simple fix for this yet my knowledge of python/django is just not quite there.

Thanks for any assistance!

edit:  the answer provided below seems promising, yet seems to pass regardless.  I'd like the test to fail unless there is an exact match on the regex (i.e error message) and the error type (in this case an AssertionError)

Comment: But you don't seem to be passing any kind of function to assertRaises, just two sets of usernames. What are you expecting to happen?

Comment: And anyway,  why do you want to test for an error raised by another test?

Comment: Well I don't want to make a second test per se.  I was thinking that testing for this specific error would be better than just testing to see if xyz exists in abc.  Just figured this was a better practice so to speak, testing for errors instead..

Comment: basically i want to test for the assertion error that will pop up when one trires to add a username that either exists or doest not in the db. and i was hoping that the .format would allow me to insert the 'fake' and 'real' names into the assertRaises but clearly am not using it properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assertRaises usage looks like follows:

```
self.assertRaises(InvalidOperation, Decimal, '25,34')
```

> Fail unless an exception of class excClass is raised by callableObj
>   when invoked with arguments args and keyword arguments kwargs.

Decimal is the callable in example, '25,34' is arg.

In your case use assertRaisesMessage:

```
def test_clean_username(self):
  self.assertRaisesMessage(
      AssertionError, '"{0}" unexpectedly found in "{1}"'.format(
          self.proposed_username,
          self.taken_usernames,
          )
      )
```

> Asserts that expected_message is found in the the message of a raised
>   exception.

Comment: this seems promising...thank you for the explanation

it seems to pass regardless of what I have in string?  for instance I switch 'unexpectedly found in' to 'yoyoyo' it still passes...is that because:

Asserts that expected_message is found in the the message of a raised exception.

so its passing because it exists in the message?  I"m looking for an exact match more or less

Comment: If we look inside implementation it uses assertIn. If you have expected message 'test' and exception 'xxx test yyy', then it passes. So try to use exact message for testing.

Comment: Have you tested it?

Comment: that makes sense; thank you.  I'm looking into it now.  I was almost thinking I should be using regular 'assert ==' might have made it easier.  It seems theres not an assertRaisesExactMessage...Is this what the assertRaises/Warns Regex comes in handy?

Comment: assertRaisesRegexp is using re.search() so there is no difference in behaviour on the same data. assertRaisesMessage checks for the exception type and exact message. It's your task to provide tests with expected data and there is no need to exact matching, because in tests you reproducing specific situation.

Comment: I see.  I think i need to think about how to better design these tests to begin with and take a step back.  Thank you for your time and assistance!